# [verilog]Activating LED with Pmod_KYPD combination

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm using a [Pmod_KYPD](https://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,401,940&Prod=PMODKYPD) connected to a [Digilent FPGA](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=NEXYS2).

My purpose is to activate the first LED on the board after the combination '123' is entered in to the keypad.

I've downloaded the [demo code](https://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/PMOD-KPD/PmodKYPD_ISE_Demo.zip) of the keypad from Digilent which works fine and it basically displays whatever pressed on from the keypad on to the 7-segment display.

The demo code is composed of two parts, which are decode and display. I've modified the display code(only the second 'always' statement is my addition) like the following with a statement machine:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: Digilent Inc 2011
// Engineer: Michelle Yu  
//               Josh Sackos
// Create Date:    07/23/2012 
//
// Module Name:    DisplayController
// Project Name:   PmodKYPD_Demo
// Target Devices: Nexys3
// Tool versions:  Xilinx ISE 14.1 
// Description: This file defines a DisplayController that controls the seven segment display that works with 
//               the output of the Decoder.
//
// Revision History: 
//                      Revision 0.01 - File Created (Michelle Yu)
//                          Revision 0.02 - Converted from VHDL to Verilog (Josh Sackos)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// ==============================================================================================
//                                              Define Module
// ==============================================================================================
module DisplayController(
DispVal,
anode,
segOut,
 led,
 clk,
 reset
);

 input clk;
 input reset;

// ==============================================================================================
//                                          Additional Declarations
// ==============================================================================================

 output reg [7:0] led;
 reg [1:0] state;

// ==============================================================================================
//                                          Port Declarations
// ==============================================================================================

input [3:0] DispVal;            // Output from the Decoder
output [3:0] anode;             // Controls the display digits
output [6:0] segOut;            // Controls which digit to display

// ==============================================================================================
//                                  Parameters, Regsiters, and Wires
// ==============================================================================================

// Output wires and registers
wire [3:0] anode;
reg [6:0] segOut;

// ==============================================================================================
//                                              Implementation
// ==============================================================================================

// only display the rightmost digit
assign anode = 4'b1110;

//------------------------------
//         Segment Decoder
// Determines cathode pattern
//   to display digit on SSD
//------------------------------
always @(DispVal) begin
        case (DispVal)

                4'h0 : segOut <= 7'b1000000;  // 0
                4'h1 : segOut <= 7'b1111001;  // 1
                4'h2 : segOut <= 7'b0100100;  // 2
                4'h3 : segOut <= 7'b0110000;  // 3
                4'h4 : segOut <= 7'b0011001;  // 4
                4'h5 : segOut <= 7'b0010010;  // 5
                4'h6 : segOut <= 7'b0000010;  // 6
                4'h7 : segOut <= 7'b1111000;  // 7
                4'h8 : segOut <= 7'b0000000;  // 8
                4'h9 : segOut <= 7'b0010000;  // 9
                4'hA : segOut <= 7'b0001000;    // A
                4'hB : segOut <= 7'b0000011;    // B
                4'hC : segOut <= 7'b1000110;    // C
                4'hD : segOut <= 7'b0100001;    // D
                4'hE : segOut <= 7'b0000110;    // E
                4'hF : segOut <= 7'b0001110;    // F
                default : segOut <= 7'b0111111;

        endcase
end





always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(reset) begin
        led <= 8'b11111111;
        state <= 0;
    end

    else begin
        case (state)

            2'b00: begin 
                if(DispVal == 1) begin
                    state <= state + 1;
                end
                //led <= 8'b10000000;
            end

            2'b01: begin 
                if(DispVal == 2) begin
                    state <= state + 1;
                end
                else
                    state <= 0;
                //led <= 8'b00000010;
            end

            2'b10: begin 
                if(DispVal == 3) begin
                    state <= state + 1;
                end
                else
                    state <= 0;
                //led <= 8'b00000100;
            end

            2'b11: begin
                led <= 8'b11111111;
            end

            default: led <= 0;

        endcase
    end
end

endmodule
```

But my modification is not working unfortunately. If I enter '123' from the keypad, the LED simply doesn't get activated.

What should I change in my modification?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a condition that keeps the current state. Example:

```
        2'b01: begin 
            if(DispVal == 2) begin
                state <= state + 1;
            end
            else if(DispVal == 1) 
                state <= state; // keep current state
            else
                state <= 0;
            //led <= 8'b00000010;
        end
```

Note: this is assuming `DispVal` is sticky (i.e., it holds it value until a different key is pressed). If not, then add logic or states to handle the no key press condition.

Debug suggestion: if you do not a a simulator, then un-comment the commented-out `led <=` in the state machine. This will allow monitoring of the state order